# simple open div layout

Tags: html

I am trying to make a simplistic layout for my website.
I want this navigation bar to fill the screen horizontally but the page content to be centered.
I have managed to achieve this, but it breaks when the content gets bigger than its predefined width.
I have only a few pages where reports and tables push the design wider than its default so would like these pages to expand nicely.
Currently the moment my content gets to wide, it hugs the left of its container but pushes the right margin out.
I would like this to push the left and right margins out equally and remain in the center.
How can I achieve this? Here is my current html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <style>
   body{margin-top: 10; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; padding:0 0 0 0;}
   #main{width: 100%; margin: auto auto;min-height:100%;}
   #header{width: 740px;position:relative;margin: auto auto;border: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: none;background-image: url('/resources/images/General/hdr_bg.png');}
   #nav{width: 100%; text-align: center; height: 31px; margin: auto auto;background-color:#c3daf9;border-top:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
   #content{width: 740px;position:relative;margin: auto auto; padding-top: 10px;}
   #footer{position: absolute; font-size: 11px; color: Gray; border-top: 1px solid #303030; bottom: 0px; width: 100%;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="main">
   <div id="header">LOGO</div>
   <div id="nav">LINK | LINK | LINK</div>
   <div id="content">
    here is some contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent
   </div>
   <div id="footer">footer content</div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I have simulated the content getting wider by making a really really long word.
In my site this would typically be a report in an HTML table.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

edit:

this isn't just about text which can be wrapped or broken.
Consider replacing the "contentcontentcontent" above with a table that is wider than its parent div:

```
<table border="1" width="800px"><tr><td>here is some content</td></tr></table>
```

This table now touches the left border of the content div, but pushes out the right border of the content div. I want it to push out both borders equally and remain in the center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone who is not a member on this site managed to solve this problem for me.
What we did is set the content div to 100%, then place a div inside this surrounding the content with align="center"

```
<div align="center"><table border="1" width="1000px" ><tr><td>here is some content</td></tr></table></div>
```

The entire solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
    <head> 
        <style> 
            body{margin-top: 10; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; padding:0 0 0 0;} 
            #main{width: 100%; margin: auto auto;min-height:100%;} 
            #header{width: 740px;position:relative;margin: auto auto;border: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: none;background-image: url('/resources/images/General/hdr_bg.png');} 
            #nav{width: 100%; text-align: center; height: 31px; margin: auto auto;background-color:#c3daf9;border-top:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;} 
            #content{width: 100%;position:relative;margin: auto auto; padding-top: 10px;border: solid 1px;}
            #footer{position: absolute; font-size: 11px; color: Gray; border-top: 1px solid #303030; bottom: 0px; width: 100%;} 
        </style> 
    </head> 
<body> 
    <div id="main"> 
        <div id="header"><br/>LOGO<br/></div> 
        <div id="nav">LINK | LINK | LINK</div> 
        <div id="content">
            <div align="center"><table border="1" width="1000px" ><tr><td>here is some content</td></tr></table></div>
        </div> 
        <div id="footer">footer content</div> 
    </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: ..I was just going to suggest this. Seriously :D

Comment: What happened to the long-word scenario? Type a very very long word (larger than 1000 px) and then watch what happens.

Comment: @vikash this still works perfectly. Swap the centered div with the following and it still remains in the center like i wanted: "<div align="center">here is sooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooome content</div> "

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it (Scroll to MidiMagic's post): http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread57605.html

Comment: this seems to explain how to center objects in a div which i've already managed to do. I'm worried about the case where my content grows larger than its parent div and seems to prefer to grow out the right of the parent div rather than proportionally

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap words in div#content.

You can use something like this:

```
div#content {
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla */
white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4 - 6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS3  */
word-wrap: break-word; /* IE 5.5+ */
}
```

Comment: You need to wrap the words in "td". you should also use `table-layout: fixed`

Comment: but this isn't only about text, it's about table width. I will update my post, but replace the content with table with a width of 800px and see how it touches the left border of the content div but pushes out the right border

Comment: If you set `table-layout: fixed` property for the table and provide width in "td", the table will not resize automatically.

Comment: unfortunately these tables are generated by a third party library based on database queries so there width cannot be fixed

Comment: If you can change the CSS, then you can set the width.